# how to create facebook event in an android app?

Tags: android, facebook, events

I m working on an small android project to create facebook events and sharing photos on it . Well I'm succeded in login and logout methods but i m still blocking in the creation of new event, I tried the old method using the:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putString("privacy_type", "OPEN");
            params.putString("name", "This is a test event");
            params.putString("start_time", "2013-12-02T18:00:00+0530");
            params.putString("end_time", "2013-12-02T20:00:00+0530");
            params.putString("description", "This is test description yeah?.");
            params.putString("location", "Mount Lavinia");

                params.putString("privacy_type", "OPEN");
                String response = "";
                Facebook facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
                AsyncFacebookRunner  mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
                   mAsyncRunner.request("me/events", params, "POST",
                        new RequestListener() {
public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
                            try {

                            Log.i(TAG, "start");
                            JSONObject event = new JSONObject(response);
                            Log.i(TAG, response);
                            String event_id = event.getString("id");
                            Log.i(TAG, "end");
                            Log.i(TAG, "Event id => " + event_id);

                            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            // "New Event Created!!",
                            // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } catch (Exception e) {

                        }
                    }
                }, null);
```

and the new method:

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
         Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putString("privacy_type", "OPEN");
            params.putString("name", "This is a test event");
            params.putString("start_time", "2013-12-02T18:00:00+0530");
            params.putString("end_time", "2013-12-02T20:00:00+0530");
            params.putString("description", "This is test description yeah?.");
            params.putString("location", "Mount Lavinia");

        new Request(
                session,
                "me/events",
                params,
                HttpMethod.POST,
                  new Request.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                        /* handle the result */
                        try {
                            Log.i(TAG, response.toString());

                            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            // "New Event Created!!",
                            // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "noresponse");
                        }
                    }
                }
            ).executeAsync();
```

but Im always getting this in the LogCat :

07-04 05:50:48.749: I/MainActivity(3159): {Response: responseCode: 200, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: -1, errorCode: -1, errorType: null, errorMessage: java.lang.NullPointerException}, isFromCache:false}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

> Create event Removed - Apps can no longer create events with the API.

This is no longer possible, unfortunately.

Comment: Think you any way for your answer but Im still loocking for a method to create facbook event from android app !!! can you help me with that ??

Comment: it is not possible (anymore). there is no workaround for this ;)

Comment: @HoNzO, did you manage to find a way? Having the same question now and other than playing the the DOM of the Facebook page, I've got nothing. Playing with the DOM is tricky though as they could easily change that later on and my integration won't work anymore ... so not the best choice.

Comment: what you are trying to do is most likely not allowed. there is no legal way, that´s just how it is.

Comment: But Facebook official app is able to create events. Any idea how?

Comment: the answer is in your comment. "official app".