# How can I add an event to a Facebook page in Android Studio?

Tags: android, facebook, events

I'm developing an application for a sport society and they asked to me to develop a button that create an event on facebook. For examples: for tonight match or for a special team dinner.

I read that there is a tool provided by facebook but I can't find how to use it.
First of all, is it possible? Then, how can I do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24574230/3364266 this may help you

Comment: It's datet 2015. It's still valid?